# Use of TransactionScope with Databases in C#

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

Consider the sample code fragment given below.

Do the changes done to database gets reverted when I do not write  `transaction.Complete();` in the end ?

```
   using (var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
    {

      var database = new DatabaseContext();

      var userA = database.Users.Find(1);

      var userB = database.Users.Find(2);
      userA.Name = "Admin";

      database.SaveChanges();
      userB.Age = 28;
      database.SaveChanges();
      transaction.Complete(); // Do changes done by database.saveChanges(); gets reverted if this statement is ommited ? 
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is really easy to test. Comment out the line and look at what happens

Comment: Why this question? Commenting out the line should prove that rolling back works. Have you encountered different behaviour? Is there another question behind this?

Comment: For a complete explanation have a look into MSDN  [at the method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.

But why do you need it? In the given example a simple database context does what you are asking for.

If you don't call `database.SaveChanges()` the next time database will open a new connection on that specific location it will not contain the old data.

I'm a little bit cautious about transaction scopes...

Comment: The above code was just for illustration purpose. I am writing test methods for a framework. The test need to clean the data written to database as soon as It gets completed.

I think wrapping the test method in Transaction Scope is a good way of doing it rather than cleaning the Data at Test Cleanup method. Any further inputs and suggestions are most welcome. :)

Comment: But, that' my point. You don't really need a transaction scope, database context do it. 
Well, it depends on the approach you are following.
I needed to use a transaction scope 1 or 2 times when i created multiple database contexts (wrong approach) inside the same logic flow.

Comment: This is the case with me too. My test methods are using multiple database contexts and it modifies data in those contexts. Transaction scope will take care of handling these multiple contexts.

Comment: In that case that's the only option. But keep in mind that using multiple contexts isn't the right approach. But it heavily depends on which platform/technology you are using (mvc, forms, etc...). You can always implement the "On context per request" approach, which there is only one context per single request. If you don't do savechanges it will not save anything, which can occur with your approach (w/o transaction) if an exception occurs between two savechanges.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

From here...

```
// The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
        // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
        scope.Complete();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396